# how to mount filesystem on to an existing (non-empty) directory?

Tags: mount

How can I mount a new fs (fuse) on to an existing directory where my application is writing? 
Details on the issue:
I have /var mounted as ext4. My application writes the data to /var/lib directory (/var/lib is NOT mounted). How may I do this without restarting my application? 
On trying to create a mount for /var/lib, I see following message. I am worried about losing existing data in /var/lib to continue with option "nonempty".
"

> starting fuse filesystem fuse: mountpoint is not empty 
>   fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option

"

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As message states you need to pass `nonempty` mount option:

```
sudo mount.fuse /dev/device /var/lib/your_folder -o nonempty
```

See [`man mount.fuse`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) for details:

> **nonempty**
>                 Allows mounts over a non-empty file or directory.  By  default  these   mounts  are
>                 rejected to prevent accidental covering up of data, which could for example prevent
>                 automatic backup.

Note: you should not mount directly to `/var/lib` as it is used by many applications.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is this possible to achieve the said/mentioned issue using bind mount option? My intention is to test Disk Latency using Charybdefs by skylla. Charybdefs is a fuse based implementation, where the mount will be created onto which the disk latency to be injected / validated. Since my application writes most of its data onto /car/lib, I wanted to mount Charybdefs onto to /var/lib so that, each write operation on to /var/lib will be impacted. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve mount /var/lib without app restart.

Comment: How about run your application in a chroot, or rewrite it so it doesn't write to /var/lib (why would you do that?).

Comment: Note that FUSE**3** changelog [states](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/ChangeLog.rst#libfuse-300-2016-12-08) that: *The `-o nonempty` mount point has been removed, mounting over non-empty directories is now always allowed. This brings the behavior of FUSE file systems in-line with the behavior of the regular mount command.

File systems that do not want to allow mounting to non-empty directories should perform this check themselves before handing control to `libfuse`.*

Answer (score 3):

You can mount as described in other answer, but the data in the directory you mount on (/var/lib/) will not be available until you unmoumt again. This means that other programs using /var/lib/ might fail.

AND, depending on how your application handles the files it write to, it might not work at all. If the program opens the file at start, do multiple writes, and then closes the file just before it terminates, you might have a stale filehandle and writes fails. If on the other hand, the program do open - write - close, each time it writes the file, it might work.

Comment: Will this actually fail? I'd expect file handle to stay valid since underlying FS is still there, even if masked.